# Notice: Array to String Conversion in /xxx/ line 33

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am not skilled in PHP at all, and I am getting this error

> Notice: Array to String Conversion in :

And it directs me to line 33  (which is below):

```
/**
 * Generates a security token
 * The token isn't stored into the database and this avoids a database schema change
 * and SQL queries to store, retrieve, and purge (expired) tokens
 * If set to, will expire in TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIMEFRAME seconds unless otherwise specified
 *
 * @param array $context information to base the token on
 * @param array $options (such as expires, timestamp, key)
 * @return string generated token
 */
function generate($context, $options = array(  )) {
        $context = implode( '/', (array)$context ); // <-- Line #33

                                                                  `
```

Comment: I guess the error is here: `(string)$options['expires']`, but you have to show us your **full** code, so that we can help you

Comment: sorry I added the rest

Comment: you didn't add enough. this can't be properly debugged without seeing the value of `$options`

Comment: Please also note which line exactly is line 33~

Comment: line 33 is :  $context = implode( '/', (array)$context );

Comment: You get this if any of the array entries in `$context` are themselves arrays. `implode` only works on simple, flat arrays. See https://eval.in/283822

Comment: This is impossible to debug without seeing how you're calling the `generate()` method